# How to preserve path and query string parameters after page refresh in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have AngularJS application with the following route define using $routeProvider

```
$routeProvider        
        .when('/users/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'components/user-management/view-users/view.html'
            controller: 'viewUsersCtrl'            
        })
        .when('/users/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'components/user-management/edit-user/view.html'
            controller: 'editUserCtrl'   
            reloadOnSearch:  false                    
        })
        .otherwise {redirectTo: '/'}
```

When requesting/putting the following URL in browser

```
webapp/#/users/edit/3
```

it retrieves the details of the user, but after you hit the browser's refresh button, the following URL will then take over.

```
webapp/#/users/edit/:id
```

which will results to no user.

How am I going to preserved the path/query string variables so that when I hit the refresh button it will stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already implemented it in my angular.run method:

```
$routeScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(e, next, current) {
    $rootScope.queryString = $location.search()
})

$routeScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(e, next, current) {
    $location.search($rootScope.queryString);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use $stateProvider instead of $routeProvider:

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);

    app.config(function($stateProvider) {           

        var users = {
                name: 'users',
                url: '/users',      
                templateUrl: 'users.html'
            },          
            viewUsers = {
                name: 'view-user',          
                url: '/edit',
                parent: users,
                templateUrl: 'view-users.html'
                //controller: 'viewUsersCtrl'               
            },
            editUser = {
                name: 'edit-user',          
                url: '/:id',
                parent: viewUsers,
                templateUrl: 'edit-user.html'
                //controller: 'eidtUsersCtrl'               
            };

        $stateProvider.state(users);
        $stateProvider.state(viewUsers);
        $stateProvider.state(editUser);
    });     

})();
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UI-ROUTER</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">        
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <a href="#" ui-sref="users">Users</a>               
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**users.html**:

```
<h3>users</h3>
<div ui-view></div>
```

**view-users.html**:

```
<h3>VIEW USER</h3>
<div ui-view></div>
```

**edit-user.html**:

```
<h3>EDIT USER</h3>
```

Comment: Can you show me how to resolve my issue using $stateProvider, maybe you can show some code? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the response to show you how to do the job with $stateProvider

Comment: thanks for your example, but this doesn't preserve the query string or path variables upon page refresh.